# Weighing loss of one class higher than others in deep learning

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

While using keras, particularly for a U-net, I am only aware of just specifying the model parameters in the following manner:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou])
```

Now I can set the loss equal to whatever I define it to be. However, this loss function will be evenly applied to all classes. How do I make it so that mis-predictions for certain classes are weighed more than other mis-predictions.

For example, let's say I have the following classes in each image.
Class **A**, **B**, and **C**. Now, class A and B account for about 45% of the entire image and class C only accounts for about 10% of the entire image. However, I care much more about having high prediction for class C.

In this situation, the loss functions don't do such a good job since the class imbalance absorbs the loss of class **c**. Hence, I would like to figure out a way to weight the loss of one class higher than the other.

I am also open to other suggestions to solving this problem - like for instance, perhaps having two separate networks?

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51793737) is a follow up to this question that will be required to implement the answer that has been accepted by this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign weights for each class manually. For example:

```
class_weight = {0: 0.2, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.25}
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou], class_weight=class_weight)
```

or you can use this scikit library [function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html)
There are also many examples in the web, didn't any of them work for you?

Comment: Nice, and so in that example, that's assuming I have 4 classes right? How do I know how much weight to assign? It arbitrary/experimental or is there a methodical way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you look at this scikit function http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html